# Knowing if an iOS application has been converted from flash

Tags: ios, air, adobe

Is there a way to figure out if an iOS application (ipa file) has been converted from Flash (swf) by Adobe Air Packaging?

Is there any clue if I check its binaries, etc.?

Comment: What do you consider "a way to understand"? Do you want to learn how this is possible or what?

Comment: @H2CO3 I think the OP is asking if there is a way to figure out if an app is built with Adobe Air or not

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Ah, I see.

Comment: Yes, I mean find out, figure out.

Answer (score 1):

If you unzip an IPA created with AIR and look at its Info.plist, you'll see a key named CTNamespaceURI with a string value of http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2 (or /3.3, /3.4...)